# Accessing parameterized type of parameterized type

Tags: java, generics

## Short question

Is it possible to anyhow do something like this in Java:

```
public interface Processor<T extends Producer> {
    <T2> T2 process(T<T2> producer);
}
```

where Producer is declared as `Producer<T>`?

## Long question

If type A in Java is parameterized with type B that is also generic, is it possible to somehow use parameterized type of B in A? I know, it is enigmatic.

Let's say we have a generic Producer interface:

```
public interface Producer<T> {
    T produce();
}
```

Implementations of this interface are meant to be generic as well. They don't differ in type of produced objects, but rather in a way how they produce them, so there could be: DatabaseProducer, RandomProducer, etc.

We have also a Processor interface. Specific implementations of processors are able to work with specific implementations of producers, but processors also do not care about the type of processed objects. We can very easily implement such case:

```
public class MyProducer<T> implements Producer<T> {
    @Override
    public T produce() {
        (...)
    }
}

public class MyProcessor implements Processor<MyProducer> {
    <T> T process(MyProducer<T> producer) {
        return producer.produce();
    }
}
```

process() method of MyProcessor gets generic MyProducer and just returns what it produced. This implementation will work with producers of String, Integer or other objects as long as the producer will be of MyProducer type.

Now the problem is how to write a generic Processor interface. This interface is parameterized with type of Producer and the method should return a parameterized type of related Producer.

We can't do something like that:

```
public interface Processor<T extends Producer> {
    <T2> T2 process(T<T2> producer);
}
```

or something like that:

```
public interface Processor<T extends Producer> {
    T.T process(T producer);
}
```

Is it even possible to do in Java? Is there any reason why it cannot or should not be supported or is this just a missing feature? I think the compiler could fully understand this scenario and check if types are ok.

---

**Update**

Solution with two parameterized types, e.g.:

```
public interface Processor<T extends Producer<T2>, T2> {
    T2 process(T producer);
}
```

is not what I'm looking for. Note that MyProcessor was not bound to any specific type of produced objects. Type returned from process() method was inferred at the call site.

Also I understand how type erasure works and problems related to it. The question is: is this case problematic or impossible due to type erasure? I believe not.

If we have a regular generic method, e.g.:

```
<T> T process(MyProducer<T> producer) {
    return producer.produce();
}
```

and we call it:

```
MyProducer<String> prod = (...);
String result = processor.process(prod);
```

then everything will be fine. Of course in such case String is erased, both process() and produce() methods return Object in resulting bytecode, but compiler understands that MyProducer.produce() will in fact return String, so process() will also return String. I don't see why it could not work the same way in my case:

```
public interface Processor<T extends Producer> {
    <T2> T2 process(T<T2> producer);
}
```

Compiler infers returned type at call site from passed producer object and it can proof that implementation is correct in the same way as above. The only thing I think is missing in Java now is that the compiler should note that T extends generic type, so `T<T2>` could be treated similar to `Producer<T2>`. Maybe I don't see something important here.

Comment: The first thing you should do is enable all warnings in your Java compiler, and address those warnings.  In particular, pay attention to warnings about raw types.

Answer (score 1):

You either use generic on class level or method level. If you need to have Processor use specific type of Producer then you can have Processor be defined like this:

```
public interface Producer<T> {
    T produce();
}

public interface Processor< T, P extends Producer<T> > {
    public T process(P producer);
}

public class MyProducer<T> implements Producer<T> {
    @Override
    public T produce() {
        return null;
    }
}

public class MyProcessor<T> implements Processor<T, MyProducer<T> > {

    public T process(MyProducer<T> producer) {
        return producer.produce();
    }
}
```

**Updated 1:**

I don't see the point of making `Processor` interface generic and then using `Producer` with raw type in there. If you dont want to parametrize `Processor` to any type of `Producer` then you declare parametrized types at the method level:

```
    public static interface Processor {
        public <T> T process(Producer<T> producer);
    } 

    public static class MyProcessor implements Processor{

        public <T> T process(Producer<T> producer) {
            return producer.produce();
        }
    }

    //in here we wont have any compilation errors
    String result = new MyProcessor().process( new MyProducer<String>() );
```

BTW, I don't like how you are declaring MyProducer to be generic and not showing how you are going to know what type of object to return in `produce()` method.

**Updated 2:**

In this case I dont think we can do without casting. Here is another version without bounded `Producer` that will require casting:

```
public static interface Processor< P extends Producer<?> > {
    public <T> T process(P producer);
}

public static class MyProcessor implements Processor< MyProducer<?> > {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T process(MyProducer<?> producer) {
        return (T)producer.produce();
    }
}

//again this will work without any compilation errors
String result = new MyProcessor().process( new MyProducer<String>()
```

Comment: I actually do want to bound implementation of Processor to specific implementation of Producer. I don't want to bound it to any specific kind of produced objects though. And I removed the body of produce(), because it is irrelevant. MyProducer could have e.g. a List<T> that it received in a constructor and it produces one item at a time - whatever, really.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because your generic type is **[Non-Reifiable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/nonReifiableVarargsType.html)**

> **Non-Reifiable Types**
>
> A reifiable type is a type whose type information is fully available
>   at runtime. This includes primitives, non-generic types, raw types,
>   and invocations of unbound wildcards.
>
> Non-reifiable types are types where information has been removed at
>   compile-time by type erasure — invocations of generic types that are
>   not defined as unbounded wildcards. A non-reifiable type does not have
>   all of its information available at runtime. Examples of non-reifiable
>   types are List and List; the JVM cannot tell the
>   difference between these types at runtime. As shown in Restrictions on
>   Generics, there are certain situations where non-reifiable types
>   cannot be used: in an instanceof expression, for example, or as an
>   element in an array.

A very simplistic workaround could be done by using an additional type in your interface:

```
public interface Processor<T extends Producer, T2> {
    T2 process(T producer);
}
```

**Answering to the Question Update:**

I would say that it is impossible in this case because `Producer` does not have an actual relation with `T`. What is possible is creating an inner class inside the `Producer` interface and use it as a type:

```
public interface Producer<T>{
    T produce();

    class NotGenericType <T>{
        // inner T != outter T 
        // do something with T ?
    }
}

public interface Processor<P extends Producer>{
    // NotGenericType belongs to the type P
    P.NotGenericType process(P producer);

    // Won't work because there is no relation between T and Producer
    // P.T process(P producer);
}
```

I didn't think about what use this could have, though.

Comment: @broot, please take a look